# Spring Security Login Redirects to /j_spring_security_check Without Authenticating

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am currently trying to get a simple Spring security login to work. I am using mongodb and can get users to be saved to the database (can query them from mongo shell). However, when I enter the credentials into the login form, I get redirected to /j_spring_security_check and I'm not sure if the authentication is even being attempted. Here's the console output after I attempt to login:

```
11:19:10.625 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/accounts/j_spring_security_check at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
11:19:10.625 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
11:19:10.625 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@54c21095. A new one will be created.
11:19:10.626 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/accounts/j_spring_security_check at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
11:19:10.626 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/accounts/j_spring_security_check at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
11:19:10.626 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/accounts/j_spring_security_check at position 4 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
11:19:10.626 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest - pathInfo: both null (property equals)
11:19:10.626 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest - queryString: both null (property equals)
11:19:10.626 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest - requestURI: arg1=/api/accounts/admin; arg2=/api/accounts/j_spring_security_check (property not equals)
11:19:10.626 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache - saved request doesn't match
11:19:10.626 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/accounts/j_spring_security_check at position 5 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
11:19:10.626 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/accounts/j_spring_security_check at position 6 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
11:19:10.626 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90572420: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@255f8: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0; SessionId: 897C850D53E8B5AEC983E6060077E3F0; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
11:19:10.626 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/accounts/j_spring_security_check at position 7 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
11:19:10.626 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/accounts/j_spring_security_check at position 8 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
11:19:10.626 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/accounts/j_spring_security_check at position 9 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
11:19:10.626 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/api/accounts/j_spring_security_check'; against '/api/accounts/login'
11:19:10.626 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/api/accounts/j_spring_security_check'; against '/api/accounts/logout'
11:19:10.626 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/api/accounts/j_spring_security_check'; against '/api/accounts/accessdenied'
11:19:10.626 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/api/accounts/j_spring_security_check'; against '/api/accounts/admin'
11:19:10.626 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Public object - authentication not attempted
11:19:10.626 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/accounts/j_spring_security_check reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
11:19:10.626 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' processing POST request for [/hdft-rest-api/api/accounts/j_spring_security_check]
11:19:10.627 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /api/accounts/j_spring_security_check
11:19:10.641 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/api/accounts/j_spring_security_check]
11:19:10.641 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/api/accounts/j_spring_security_check] are [/**]
11:19:10.641 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/api/accounts/j_spring_security_check] are {}
11:19:10.641 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/api/accounts/j_spring_security_check] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler@29ab0eef] and 1 interceptor
11:19:10.641 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
11:19:10.641 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
11:19:10.641 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
11:19:10.641 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
11:19:10.641 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
11:19:10.641 [tomcat-http--7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

I've attached the relevant configuration files:

Here's my spring-security.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled" />

<http auto-config="false"  use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/api/accounts/accessdenied">
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/accounts/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/accounts/logout" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/accounts/accessdenied" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/accounts/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <form-login login-page="/api/accounts/login" default-target-url="/api/accounts/welcome" authentication-failure-url="/api/accounts/accessdenied"  />
    <logout logout-success-url="/api/accounts/logout" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="mongoUserDetailsService" class="com.services.impl.MongoUserDetailsService" />

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="mongoUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

MongoUserDetailsService.java:

```
@Component
public class MongoUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Resource
private UserRepository urepo;

private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User userdetails;

public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    boolean enabled = true;
    boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    boolean accountNonLocked = true;
    com.DTOs.users.User user = urepo.findByUsername(username);

    userdetails = new User(user.getUsername(), 
                           user.getPassword(),
                           enabled,
                           accountNonExpired,
                           credentialsNonExpired,
                           accountNonLocked,
                           getAuthorities(user.getRole()));

    return userdetails;
}

public List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer role) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    if (role.intValue() == 1) {
        authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));

    } else if (role.intValue() == 2) {
        authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    }
    System.out.println(authList);
    return authList;
}
```

User.java POJO:

```
@Document
public class User {

@Id
private String id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String username;
private int role;
private String password;

public User(String id, String firstName, String lastName, String username, int role, String password) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.username = username;
    this.role = role;
    this.password = password
}

// setter and getter methods...
```

And finally my login.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %

<html>
    <body>
    <h1 id="banner">Spring 3 security MongoDB Demo</h1>

    <form name="f" action="j_spring_security_check" method="post">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input id="username" name="j_username"></br>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input id="password" name="j_password" type='password'></br>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login"/>
    </form>

</body>
```

Please let me know if you see where I'm going wrong or need additional information. It would be much appreciated.

Edit:

I tried the suggestion in the comment below. It is attempting authentication, but the authentication is failing. I checked my mongodb and I'm definitely entering the credentials correctly so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is the new error log:

```
11:07:28.794 [tomcat-http--12] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /j_spring_security_check at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
11:07:28.794 [tomcat-http--12] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
11:07:28.794 [tomcat-http--12] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@7f10f850. A new one will be created.
11:07:28.794 [tomcat-http--12] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /j_spring_security_check at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
11:07:28.794 [tomcat-http--12] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /j_spring_security_check at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
11:07:28.794 [tomcat-http--12] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Request is to process authentication
11:07:28.794 [tomcat-http--12] DEBUG o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
11:07:28.794 [tomcat-http--12] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException
11:07:28.794 [tomcat-http--12] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
11:07:28.794 [tomcat-http--12] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@52e16021
11:07:28.794 [tomcat-http--12] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler - Redirecting to /api/accounts/accessdenied
11:07:28.794 [tomcat-http--12] DEBUG o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to '/hdft-rest-api/api/accounts/accessdenied'
11:07:28.794 [tomcat-http--12] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
11:07:28.794 [tomcat-http--12] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
11:07:28.796 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/accounts/accessdenied at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
11:07:28.796 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
11:07:28.796 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@7f10f850. A new one will be created.
11:07:28.796 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/accounts/accessdenied at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
11:07:28.796 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/accounts/accessdenied at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
11:07:28.796 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/accounts/accessdenied at position 4 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
11:07:28.796 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest - pathInfo: both null (property equals)
11:07:28.796 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest - queryString: both null (property equals)
11:07:28.796 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest - requestURI: arg1=/hdft-rest-api/api/accounts/admin; arg2=/hdft-rest-api/api/accounts/accessdenied (property not equals)
11:07:28.796 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache - saved request doesn't match
11:07:28.796 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/accounts/accessdenied at position 5 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
11:07:28.796 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/accounts/accessdenied at position 6 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
11:07:28.796 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6faa6108: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff10d0: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0; SessionId: 7A0F91CF4FD4ADA0A192E2EDE53AADB0; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
11:07:28.797 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/accounts/accessdenied at position 7 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
11:07:28.797 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/accounts/accessdenied at position 8 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
11:07:28.797 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/accounts/accessdenied at position 9 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
11:07:28.797 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/api/accounts/accessdenied'; against '/api/accounts/login'
11:07:28.797 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/api/accounts/accessdenied'; against '/api/accounts/logout'
11:07:28.797 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/api/accounts/accessdenied'; against '/api/accounts/accessdenied'
11:07:28.797 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /api/accounts/accessdenied; Attributes: [permitAll]
11:07:28.797 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6faa6108: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff10d0: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0; SessionId: 7A0F91CF4FD4ADA0A192E2EDE53AADB0; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
11:07:28.797 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@7de6385e, returned: 1
11:07:28.797 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful
11:07:28.797 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
11:07:28.797 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/accounts/accessdenied reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
11:07:28.797 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' processing GET request for [/hdft-rest-api/api/accounts/accessdenied]
11:07:28.797 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /api/accounts/accessdenied
11:07:28.797 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.schneiderlab.hdft_mobile.rest_api.UserController.loginerror(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)]
11:07:28.797 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'userController'
11:07:28.798 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/hdft-rest-api/api/accounts/accessdenied] is: -1
11:07:28.798 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'denied'; URL [/WEB-INF/views/denied.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
11:07:28.798 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Added model object 'error' of type [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'denied'
11:07:28.798 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/views/denied.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'denied'
11:07:28.799 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
11:07:28.799 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
11:07:28.799 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
11:07:28.799 [tomcat-http--13] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're POSTing your credentials to "/api/accounts/j_spring_security_check", while the monitored URL is just "/j_spring_security_check". You should construct the action URL in the form using:

```
<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check"/>
```

So the result would be:

```
<form name="f" action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check"/>" method="post">
```

**Update after changed question...**

Your authentication fails throwing Exception or returning null. The result of call to your UserDetailsProvider are checked like this (inside DaoAuthenticationProvider) with the result of throwing AuthenticationServiceException:

```
    try {
        loadedUser = this.getUserDetailsService().loadUserByUsername(username);
    } catch (UsernameNotFoundException notFound) {
        throw notFound;
    } catch (Exception repositoryProblem) {
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException(repositoryProblem.getMessage(), repositoryProblem);
    }

    if (loadedUser == null) {
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException(
                "UserDetailsService returned null, which is an interface contract violation");
    }
```

You should:

- improve your code to include some logging
- start debugger and go through your code to see what fails or returns null
- or implement a custom AuthenticationFailureHandler which will print complete content of the exception it receives as a parameter and plug it instead of the default one

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried this and it attempted the authentication, but for some reason still failed. I have posted my error log in my edit.

Comment: Hey @s3wix I'd suggest giving credit for this answer - just check the green checkmark to the left of the answer.